# How to set the httpd.conf when using php-fpm with php(5.3.8) and apache2?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, settings, php-fpm

I want to use fastcgi in apache2 with php(5.3.8).

I installed fastcgi_module in apache, and compiled php with--enable-fpm.
I also found some tutorials，there were two methods in their settings:

> > FastCgiServer /usr/local/apache2/fcgi-bin/php-cgi -processes 10

or

> > FastCgiExternalServer /usr/local/apache2/fcgi-bin/php-cgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000

But I can not find the **php-cgi** in php 5.3.8. what should I do next？ 
How to set the httpd.conf when using php-fpm with php(5.3.8) and apache2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The secret here is that `php-cgi` is nto a real file, it's a wrong file name use internally in Apache. You could call it as well : `false-php-cgi-catcher-which-do-not-exists`.

I wrote a [complete php-fpm+apache2.2+chroot install guide](http://www.makina-corpus.org/blog/install-drupal-php-fpm-fastcgi-apache-and-chroot-php-fpm) a few days ago here. You may have a look. But try to get it working without the chroot first. Note that starting with apache 2.3 the best tool for php-fpm will be [mod_proxy_fcgi](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html)

Here's an extract of the complete install guide. I use `php5.external` where you want to use `php-cgi`.

```
# phpfpm/fastcgi
# Here we catch the 'false' Location used to inexistent php5.external
# and push it to the external FastCgi process via a socket
# note: socket path is relative to FastCgiIpcDir
# which is set in Main configuration /etc/apache2/mods-available/fastcgi.conf
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    # all .php files will be pushed to a php5-fcgi handler
    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php

    #action module will let us run a cgi script based on handler php5-fcgi
    Action php5-fcgi /fcgi-bin/php5.external

    # and we add an Alias to the fcgi location
    Alias /fcgi-bin/php5.external /php5.external

    # now we catch this cgi script which in fact does not exists on filesystem
    # we catch it on the url (Location)
    <Location /fcgi-bin/php5.external>
        # here we prevent direct access to this Location url,
        # env=REDIRECT_STATUS will let us use this fcgi-bin url
        # only after an internal redirect (by Action upper)
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
        Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
    </Location>
</IfModule>
FastCgiExternalServer /php5.external -socket myapplication.sock -appConnTimeout 30 -idle-timeout 60
```